# WCF transport security (https) and metadata exchange (mex) is not possible?

Tags: c#, wcf, xaml, tcp, config

I want to host a web service via WCF and the transport should be encrypted/secured (using https). I still want to be able to download the metadata via net.tcp (using mex).

web config

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6"/>
        <httpModules>
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
        </httpModules>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MetadataExchangeBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
          <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="TransportSecurityBinding">
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
          <service name="Service.Interface.ApplicationService" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataExchangeBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurityBinding" name="wsHttpEndpoint" contract="Service.Interface.IApplicationService"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" kind="mexEndpoint"/>
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="https://localhost:9800/ApplicationService"/>
                <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9900/ApplicationService"/>
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
            preCondition="managedHandler"/>
        </modules>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

apllicationhost config

```
<listenerAdapters>
      <add name="http" />
    </listenerAdapters>

    <sites>
      <site name="Service.Interface" id="1">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Offline Files\Software Files\Program Files\Microsoft\Visual Studio\Workspaces\PinIt\PinIt\Developing\Service\Service.Interface" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9800:localhost" />
        </bindings>
      </site>
      <siteDefaults>
        <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
      </siteDefaults>
      <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
      <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>
```

The link to the metadata should be: `net.tcp://localhost:9900/ApplicationService/mex`, but if i try to the service to the WCF Test Client following error is thrown:

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://localhost:9900/ApplicationService/mex 
If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. 
For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata 
Exchange Error URI: net.tcp://localhost:9900/ApplicationService/mex Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:9900/ApplicationService/mex'. 
Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:9900/ApplicationService/mex. 
The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0008800. 
TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9900. 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9900
```

I used netstat to figure out if the port was listening. Only 9800 was listening: Proof

**Summary:** What I want:

- WCF Service using https on port 9800
- Transport should be secured with a username and password
- Metadata exchange using net.tcp on port 9900

What doesn't work:

- Can't obtain metadata
- Port 9900 not listening

Comment: Are you doing Self-Hosting (running from a .exe or a windows service) or are you hosting inside IIS. The answer to you problem may be different depending on which you are doing.

Comment: Also, why not simplify your setup and use [`mexHttpsBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967391(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Currently i am using the Test Client from Visual Studio, so IIS (Express) and i probably will use IIS for the final product.

I will try the `mexHttpsBinding`, whish me luck ^^